# Automatically move Wordpress post from one page to another after date has passed

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm designing a website for a local performing arts venue, and I would like to add some code so that specific event posts on the "Events" page will automatically be moved from "Events" to a different "Past Performances" page after the date of the event has passed. I've looked around for any existing solution to this query and haven't yet found one.

Comment: You need to look into cron.

Comment: Or you could create custom templates for `Events` page that queries only those posts that have their date higher than today's.

Comment: ^ this is the only legit answer. Moving posts with cron is a bad manner since we don't need that machine power at all, as we could query it simply by datetime. Crons are sort of overpowered here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a child theme or add page-events.php and page-past-performances.php, you may copy/paste your current theme page.php code.

Here you may choose 2 options:

1. Create a special loop for each template. For page-events.php:

   ```
   <?php 
   $today = getdate();
   $args = array('date_query' => array(
     array(
       'after' => array(
           'year' => $today['year'],
           'month' => $today['mon'],
           'day' => $today['mday'],
       ),
       'inclusive' => true
     )
   ));
   $query = WP_Query($args);
   //Here goes the loop
   ```

   For page-past-performances.php:

   ```
   <?php 
   $today = getdate();
   $args = array('date_query' => array(
     array(
       'before' => array(
           'year' => $today['year'],
           'month' => $today['mon'],
           'day' => $today['mday'],
       ),
       inclusive => false
     )
   ));
   $query = WP_Query($args);
   //Here goes the loop
   ```
2. The second option uses the action hook *pre_get_posts*, it could look something like this (inside your functions.php file):

   ```
   <?php
   add_action('pre_get_posts', 'date_filter');
   function date_filter($query) {
     if($query->pagename == 'events') {
       $query->set('date_query', [[
         'after' => //same as above
         'inclusive' => true 
       ]]);
     }
     if($query->pagename == 'past-performances') {
       $query->set('date_query', [[
         'before' => //same as above
         'inclusive' => false 
       ]]);
     }
   }
   ?>
   ```